# Can't find Define Line Portion tool

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, shapefile, editing

I am following the procedure on this help page:

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00390000002z000000

However when at step 3, I can't seem to find the *Define Line Portion* tool.

Can someone please help locate that tool?

I've also posted the picture of how my interface looks like.[image]

Answer (score 3):

This tool is there in Route Editing

[image: The tool looking for]

Drag from this box to your interface toolbar.

Comment: Perfect, thank you, this was a very basic questions but I was stuck for like hours, cheers!